# How to span columns in NSGridView or NSTableView

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I've looked everywhere and haven't found much built-in functionality for spanning columns or rows of either the NSGridView or the NSTableView. At this point I'm thinking I'm going to have to either override some methods or look for another control. I haven't been working in OSX for very long, and to make it worse I'm in Xamarin which doesn't have much out there at quite yet. If you have an answer in cocoa I could translate (or at least try).

Is there something else out there that would fit my needs better? I need a view based grid of some sort that can span rows/columns. Could someone at least point me in the general direction of a solution? Thanks!

Comment: That is not a standard Cocoa container and spanned columns/rows is not in the macOS human design guidelines and does not fit into the standard datasource, delegate protocols and Cocoa bindings setup. Typically if you have data that does not fit a consistent row/column, a single column based `NSTableView` (View based content) that contains a custom `NSTableCellView` that handles the custom content/elements. That does not mean you can not create it yourself... ;-)

Comment: There are some great WWDC content floating around: i.e. Choosing the Right  Cocoa Container View:  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/218/ https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/218p1ql8x8ga34/218/218_choosing_the_right_cocoa_container_view.pdf https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! Unfortunately I'm not the one driving requirements, so though it goes against guidelines I still need to get it done. I guess I'll start looking into extending the functionality of the NSGridView's layout engine or making my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahah! There is a MergeCells method that does exactly what I want! Why doesn't anyone know about this??

[image]

Created using:

```
MergeCellsInColumn(grid, 0, 0, 1);
MergeCellsInRow(grid, 3, 0, 1);
```

and

```
private void MergeCellsInColumn(NSGridView grid, int column, int startingRow, int endingRow)
{
    grid.MergeCells(new NSRange(column, 1), new NSRange(startingRow, endingRow - startingRow + 1));
}

private void MergeCellsInRow(NSGridView grid, int row, int startingColumn, int endingColumn)
{
    grid.MergeCells(new NSRange(startingColumn, endingColumn - startingColumn + 1), new NSRange(row, 1));
}
```

Not sure where this is available elsewhere, but this worked easily in Xamarin.Mac. Maybe it will help someone else out down the line?